# How do I open a new window and write pixels to that window in NASM x64?

Tags: linux, image, user-interface, nasm

I am making a simple app that reads from a file and renders an image from that file. The file format is 0 for a blank character and 1 for a full character. Then, my app reads from that file and outputs to the terminal the interpretation of that file.

The only problem with that is that the width and height of my images are limited. I would like to draw each pixel using a window. How can I do that in NASM x64, on Linux, without using other languages like C/C++?

I have looked everywhere and I only found something using the C Windows API in 32-bit, which doesn't answer my question or help me. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: All platforms (Windows, macOS, Linux X11, Linux Wayland) have their APIs for drawing windows, but all of those libraries are written in C. You can import a C library in NASM and call it to draw a window. Making a GUI app in plain assembler is hard, as you'd have to write pixels directly to the monitor.

Comment: Thats what i want to do, for what im doing i want to draw every pixel since it's an image render app. Is there a way I could do that?